# How to add interactive animation (using UIVievPropertyAnimator) to switch the size of the title (largeTitleDisplayMode) of the navigation bar

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uiviewanimation

I am trying to create an interactive animation to switch the navigation bar display mode when scrolling the contents of a table view in a method *scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)*. Below is a piece of code using *UIViewPropertyAnimator* and the result of code execution.

```
private lazy var animator: UIViewPropertyAnimator = {
        return UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.25, curve: .easeInOut)
    }()

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        if canTransitionToLarge && scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0 {

                    animator.addAnimations {
                        self.navBar.items?.last?.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
                        self.navBar.layoutIfNeeded()
                        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                    }
                    animator.startAnimation()
                    canTransitionToLarge = false
                }
                else if !canTransitionToLarge && scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 {

                    animator.addAnimations {
                        self.navBar.items?.last?.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
                        self.navBar.layoutIfNeeded()
                        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                    }
                    animator.startAnimation()
                    canTransitionToLarge = true
                }
    }
```

[Result of code execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21lhQ.gif)

What changes should I make to the code in order to achieve an interactive animation like in the video below?

[interactive animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZtUv.gif)